# Getting " ImportError: No module named wnf " during ERP-Next installation

Tags: python, erpnext

i am trying to install erpnext by running 'install_erpnext.py' and it gives an error message :

```
root@erpnext:~# python2.7 install_erpnext.py --create_user
useradd: user 'erpnext' already exists
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated succ                                                 essfully
Operating System = Linux
Python Version = 2.7.3
Distribution =  ubuntu
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing Packages: (This may take some time)
python python-setuptools python-dev build-essential python-mysqldb git memcached                                                 ntp vim screen htop
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MySQL Root user's Password:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing Python Modules: (This may take some time)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pre-requisites Installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing ERPNext
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERPNext Database Name: erpnext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install_erpnext.py", line 301, in <module>
  File "install_erpnext.py", line 39, in install
  File "install_erpnext.py", line 177, in install_erpnext
ImportError: No module named wnf
```

I don't know what to do now. I also try to copy the file 'erpnext/lib/wnf.py'and put it with 'install_erpnext.py' but it still gave the same error. I have already installed Python modules and other packages. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Installing over a fresh OS is highly recommended with ERPNext.